# How to modify list element within a for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to modify list elements and replace the original element with the newly modified one. However, I've noticed that the desired behavior differs depending on how I construct my for loop. For example:

```
samples = ['The cat sat on the mat.', 'The dog at my homework.']
punctuation = ['\'', '\"', '?', '!', ',', '.']

for sample in samples:
    sample = [character for character in sample if character not in punctuation]
    sample = ''.join(sample)

print(samples)

for i in range(len(samples)):
    samples[i] = [character for character in samples[i] if character not in punctuation]
    samples[i] = ''.join(samples[i])

print(samples)
```

This program outputs:

```
['The cat sat on the mat.', 'The dog at my homework.']
['The cat sat on the mat', 'The dog at my homework']
```

The second for loop is the desired output with the punctuation removed from the sentence, but I'm having trouble understanding why that happens. I've searched online and found [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-can%E2%80%99t-you-modify-lists-through-for-in-loops-in-Python) to be helpful in explaining the technical details, but I'm wondering if it's impossible to modify list elements using the first method of for loops, and if I have to resort to using functions like `range` or `enumerate` to modify list elements within loops.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the iterator is not enough,

You need to modify the list as well:

Comment: correct..in the first method you're not actually changing samples

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer and comment, guys. So if I understand correctly, the first method is simply assigning values to `sample`, but it's not actually modifying the original list and in order to modify the original list then I need to change the iterator as well?

Comment: @Seankala No in order to modify the list you need to modify the list, not the iterator

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the item in the list, not update the local variable created by the for loop. One option would be to use a `range` and update by index.

```py
for i in range(len(samples)):
    sample = [character for character in samples[i] if character not in punctuation]
    samples[i] = ''.join(sample)
```

That said, a more pythonic approach would be to use a comprehension. You can also use the regex library to do the substitution.

```py
import re
clean_samples = [
    re.sub("['\"?!,.]", "", sample)
    for sample in samples
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
samples = ['The cat sat on the mat.', 'The dog at my homework.']
punctuation = ['\'', '\"', '?', '!', ',', '.']
new_sample = []

for sample in samples:
    sample = [character for character in sample if character not in punctuation]
    sample = ''.join(sample)
    new_sample.append(sample)
print(new_sample)
```

In this case, `sample` is an iterator, not the element of the list, so when you try to modify `sample` you are not updating the element.